# Remove Values from List where Other List has TRUE/FALSE in R

Tags: r, list

I am having a little bit of trouble working with lists. I have a list that contains split up strings of words, and I need to eliminate values in that list for which the corresponding values in another list are `FALSE`.

I have defined my list as:

```
string1 = "derive sic poetry nor any creative old testament the memc the"
string2 = "indeed fitting that his last creative act should have been to"
string3 = "expression we have of the creative and redemptive power of god"
string4 = "final trust which is the creative secret of the new race" 
string5 = "on which some day a creative belief may write her message" 

context = list(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5)
splitcontext = strsplit(fullcontext, split = ' ')
```

Now my goal is to eliminate the non-words in the `splitcontext` list. I know this can be done with the `qdapDictionaries` library. Here I have defined a function to determine `TRUE` or `FALSE` regarding if a word is an English word or not.

```
library(qdapDictionaries)
is.word <- function(x) x %in% GradyAugmented
```

Now I can apply that to every element of `splitcontext` no problem:

```
indicatorlist = lapply(splitcontext, is.word)
```

My issue is deleting words out of `splitcontext` where `indicatorlist` equals `FALSE`.

How can I get this done? Thank you very much in advance for your time. Here is my flawed code -- what I can't figure out is how to loop through `indicatorlist` and `splitcontext` in parallel.

```
removefalse <- function(x){
  x[which(indicatorlist==TRUE)]
}
lapply(splitcontext, removefalse)
```

Comment: What is `fullcontext` ?  I guess you need `lapply(splitcontext, function(x) x[is.word(x)])`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for your helpful answers. I appreciate the help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have two `list`s of values and a corresponding `logical` elements, then use `Map` to extract the 'values' that correspond to TRUE values in the logical `list` of `vector`

```
Map(`[`, splitcontext, indicatorlist)
```

However, we can do this without creating an 'indicatorList'

```
lapply(splitcontext, function(x) x[is.word(x)])
```

#### data

```
fullcontext <- c(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5)
splitcontext <- strsplit(fullcontext, split = ' ')
```